# iPhone - content size of a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone

I am on a view and I will show a TableViewController.

This app is universal. So, when I show this TableViewController on iPad I will show it inside a popover and on the iPhone I will push it with a navigationController.

Inside the tableViewController class I need to know the bounds of the parent view where this object is contained, that is the internal size of the popover (on the iPad) and the size of the view where the controller were pushed on the iPhone.

How do I access these values?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `parentViewController.view.bounds`

Comment: thanks, but I am getting zero when I try this self.parentViewController.view.bounds.size.width inside viewForHeaderInSection method.